# How to produce a list of authors for a long BibTeX file?

Tags: bibtex

I have over 500 entries in a single BibTeX file, and although this may sound like a general question, is there a way of seeing all the authors or references at a glance? Ie can I create a list of all entries by author?

Regards,

Comment: So, if a  reference has 3 authors, it should be listed 3 times, one for each author?

Comment: Do you mean a list of all authors, with the entries they have authored? Like - Harrison: [1,3] - Lennon [1,2,3] - McCarney [3] etc.?

Comment: As a minimum id like different entries to be listed only once corresponding to the leading author.

Comment: For a `biblatex` solution look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83891/16895

Comment: Interesting. By the way how do you write your BibteX file? Ie just in a word processor and put the entries in higglydypigglydy? or in some sort of database program designed for it?

Comment: @HCAI, you can write a BibTeX file in a TeX editor. Simply create a file called `bibliography.bib` or similar (note the extension) and add the entries in there.

Comment: @Mythio that's what I currently do, though it's getting very cumbersome especially as some of the entries are not in either type or alphabetical order. I was wondering what other people do with that problem.I basically want to see at a quick glance what's there. Eg print author name and year of publication(s).

Comment: @HCAI BibDesk (for Mac) and JabRef are some popular software to manage you `.bib` file. Also most TeX editors (and other editors) have features to handle `.bib` files.

Comment: @HCAI, normally I just sort the entries in the `.bib` file based on year myself, but I admit that only works if you do it right from the start...sorting out 500 entries at this point could prove to be...annoying ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\nocite{*}` at the end of the document to get a complete bibliography printed, regardless of whether it is cited in the text. Does that accomplish what you want?

If you want them ordered on authors, you can look for the appropriate bibliography style. I think `plainnat` works like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{natbib} %% or this....
\usepackage{biblist}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain} %% with plainnat
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]