# referring the same author

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I would like to input items in a bibliography as follows:

Author(for example: Mike)

item 1: article

item 2: book

item 3；...

How can I do this?  Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance.
There is a little difference from others. I need the following form

Milnor, J.:

[1]. Construction of universal bundles: I, Ann. Math., (2)63:272-284 (1956).

[2]. Construction of universal bundles: II, Ann. Math., (2)63: 430-436 (1956).

Milnor, J., and M. A. Kervaire:

[3]. Bernoulli numbers, homotopy groups, and a theorem of Rohlin, Proc. Intern.
      Congr. Math., 1958.

Comment: Use different labels for each item.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How to add the name of authors?

Comment: Even we can do this like in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83845/bibliography-with-per-author-numbering-and-author-year-sort. It is still not easy. Is there any package for us to use?

Comment: You have to load `biblatex` and include the code from the answer in your preamble (alternatively, you can store it in an external file). For the format you want, numeration is not reset for each author, remove `\setcounter{@mybibcounter}{0}` from the solution given for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83845/bibliography-with-per-author-numbering-and-author-year-sort

Comment: Thanks. But where to add the bracket to the numbers?

Comment: I know how to do now, just use [\the@mybibcounter].