# Deleted author names if repeated

Tags: biblatex

First, I'm French so I'm sorry for my English level :)

During my bibliography production, I have this :
[image]

But, I want :

**LAST NAME First name**

```
  - Fasc. 176, ...
  - Fasc. 175, ...
```

So, a list of each production of this author. I think it's the same idea like if I want :

**LAST NAME First name**

```
  - Fasc. 176, ... - Fasc. 175, ...
```

I just have to keep a line off before printing the title.

I'm using personnal style derived from *authortitle* style.
Any ideas ? Thanks.

Codes :
From standard.bbx :

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}
  \newline
  \hbox{--\space}
%  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
```

From authortitle.bbx (which uses standard.bbx) :

```
\ProvidesFile{authortitle.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}

\DeclareBibliographyOption{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
     }
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}
    }

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}
      }}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthands}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\InitializeBibliographyStyle{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash} % A supp pour laisser les noms
  }

\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
  \mkbibbold{%
       {\printnames{author}}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% % virgule au début de la ligne de titre
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
    }

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}
    }

\endinput
```

Finally, biblatex.def :

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.def}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% FORMATTING COMMANDS
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Generic formatting commands and hooks
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Used in citations, bibliography and bibliography lists

\newcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\bibellipsis}{[\textellipsis\unkern]\midsentence}

% Delimiters used in citations, bibliography and bibliography lists

\newcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\newcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{}
\newcommand*{\andothersdelim}{\addspace}

\newcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\finallistdelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\newcommand*{\andmoredelim}{\addspace}

% Used in the bibliography and bibliography lists

\newcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\newcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}
\newcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}
\newcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\newunitpunct}
\newcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\newunitpunct}
\newcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\newcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addspace}
\newcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addcomma}
\newcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{0.75em}
    {\mbox{\textemdash\space}}
    {\makebox[\leftmargin][2]{%
       \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{1.25em}
         {\textendash}
         {\textemdash}
         }}}
\newcommand*{\relatedpunct}{\addspace}
\newcommand*{\relateddelim}{\adddot\par\nobreak}
\newcommand{\mkrelatedstring}{\mainlang}

% \bibsetup is a generic hook controlling the (low-level) layout of
% the bibliography and bibliography lists. The default
% definition should work fine in most cases.

\newcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
  \interlinepenalty=5000\relax
  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
  \raggedbottom
  \frenchspacing
  \biburlsetup}

% The default font of the bibliography and the bibliography lists.
% We simply reset the current font to the global defaults.

\newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}

% Some length registers which may be used to fine-tune the
% (high-level) layout of the bibliography.

% Default \bibhang to 1em if \parindent is 0 for some reason
\setlength{\bibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}{1em}{\parindent}}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{2\labelsep}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}
\setlength{\bibnamesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibinitsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{0pt}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% FIELD FORMATS (#1 is the value of the field)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% The fallback used by \printfield

\DeclareFieldFormat{default}{#1}

% The default used by \citefield

\DeclareFieldFormat{citefield}{#1}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% LITERAL LIST FORMATS (#1 is the current item)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Formatting directives for literal lists
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% The fallback used by \printlist

\DeclareListFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  #1\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

% The default used by \citelist

\DeclareListAlias{citelist}{default}

% Used in the bibliography

\DeclareListFormat{publisher}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  #1\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareListFormat{language}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{%
    \ifbibstring{#1}
      {\bibxstring{#1}}
      {\ifbibstring{lang#1}
         {\bibxstring{lang#1}}
         {#1}}}%
  \ifbibstring{#1}
    {\bibstring{#1}}
    {\ifbibstring{lang#1}
       {\bibstring{lang#1}}
       {#1}}%
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareListFormat{location}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  #1\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareListFormat[patent]{location}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:plain}%
  \ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1\isdot}%
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
  \ifnumless{\abx@pagerefstyle}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{list:plain}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
       {#1}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:init}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{pageref:comp}{#1}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}}
       {}}}

\DeclareListAlias{origlocation}{location}
\DeclareListAlias{origpublisher}{publisher}
\DeclareListAlias{institution}{default}
\DeclareListAlias{organization}{default}

% Auxiliary macros for list formatting directives
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newbibmacro*{list:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmoreitems
     }
       {\multilistdelim}
       {\lbx@finallistdelim{#1}}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{list:plain}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\multilistdelim}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{list:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmoreitems
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andmoredelim\bibstring{andmore}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{pageref:init}{%
  \let\abx@range@hold=\empty
  \def\abx@range@diff{0}%
  \def\abx@range@prev{-1}%
  \def\abx@range@this{0}%
  \def\abx@range@last{-1}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% NAME LIST FORMATS
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Argments passed to formatting directives for name lists:
%
% #1 = last name
% #2 = last name (initials)
% #3 = first name
% #4 = first name (initials)
% #5 = name prefix, a.k.a. 'von part'
% #6 = name prefix (initials)
% #7 = name affix, a.k.a. 'junior part'
% #8 = name affix (initials)

% Formatting directives for name lists
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first/first-last}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{initsonly}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#2}{#4}{#6}{#8}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% Fallback used by \printnames

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}

% Default used by \citename

\DeclareNameAlias{citename}{default}

% Used in some citations

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% Used in the bibliography

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first/first-last}
%\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{author}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editora}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorb}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorc}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}

\DeclareNameAlias{byauthor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{bybookauthor}{byauthor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditora}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditorb}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditorc}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{bytranslator}{default}

\DeclareNameAlias{withcommentator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withannotator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withintroduction}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withforeword}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withafterword}{default}

\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{#1}

% Auxiliary macros for name formatting directives
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newbibmacro*{name:last}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}
       {}
       {\ifcapital
          {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
          {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
        \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot}%

\newbibmacro*{name:first-last}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifpunctmark{'}
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
  \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}

\newbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

\newbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\lbx@initnamehook{#1}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{name:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
     }
       {\multinamedelim}
       {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{name:revsdelim}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    (
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    )
    or
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{2}}
  }
    {\revsdnamedelim}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% INDEX FORMATS FOR FIELDS (#1 is the value of the field)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% There is no need to test if a field to be indexed is empty because
% \indexfield performs this test implicitly.

% The fallback used by \indexfield

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{default}{\index{#1}}

% Used in the bibliography and in citations

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index}{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{index:title}[2]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:field}{#1}{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#2}}}

\newbibmacro*{index:field}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}{\mkbibindexfield{#2}{#3}}}

% Auxiliary macros for field indexing directives
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newbibmacro*{index:entry}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\theindexentry{\unexpanded{#1}{#2}}%
  \theindexentry
  \endgroup}

\newcommand*{\mkbibindexfield}[2]{\mkbibindexentry{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\mkbibindexentry}[2]{#1\actualoperator#2}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% INDEX FORMATS FOR LITERAL LISTS (#1 is the current item)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% The fallback used by \indexlist

\DeclareIndexListFormat{default}{\index{#1}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% INDEX FORMATS FOR NAME LISTS
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% Argments passed to indexing directives for name lists:
%
% #1 = last name
% #2 = last name (initials)
% #3 = first name
% #4 = first name (initials)
% #5 = name prefix, a.k.a 'von part'
% #6 = name prefix (initials)
% #7 = name affix, a.k.a 'junior part'
% #8 = name affix (initials)

% Indexing directives for name lists
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% The fallback used by \indexnames

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}

% Used in citations

\DeclareIndexNameAlias{labelname}{default}

% Used in the bibliography

\DeclareIndexNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareIndexNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareIndexNameAlias{bookauthor}{default}

% Auxiliary macros for name indexing directives
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

% When generating an index entry, we need to test which parts of a
% name are actually available to prevent spurious punctuation and
% spaces. Since those parts which are not available yield an empty
% argument, we can use the \ifblank test from etoolbox.sty to analyze
% the name.
%
% Note that the standard LaTeX \index command simply writes its
% argument to the .idx file without preventing expansion. This means
% that all \ifblank tests are expanded on the way and will not end
% up in the index. The index package, however, prevents expansion.
% This would lead to \ifblank ending up in the .idx file. To avoid
% that, we preprocess the index entry inside an \edef. We use
% \unexpanded to protect the \index command and the actual data from
% expansion. This definition will work with both index.sty and the
% standard indexing facilities.
%
% We also use \ifuseprefix to ensure that the name prefix is handled
% properly. \actualoperator is the so-called actual operator, as
% defined by the 'actual' specifier in the .ist file. The makeindex
% program will use the part preceeding the \actualoperator
% delimiter for sorting. The part after the delimiter is used as the
% index is printed. Note that this is not specific to biblatex, see
% the makeindex documentation for details.

\newcommand*{\actualoperator}{@}
\newcommand*{\subentryoperator}{!}

\newbibmacro*{index:name}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}{\mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}

% {<last name>}{<first name>}{<first initials>}{<last name prefix>}

\newcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifblank{#3}{}{#3 }%
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifblank{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{, #2}%
     \actualoperator
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\MakeCapital{#3} }%
     #1%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{, #2}}
    {\@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifblank{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{,}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{ #2}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{ #3}}}

% {<control sequence>}{<control sequence>}

\newcommand*{\mkbibindexsubentry}[2]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{\subentryoperator#1\actualoperator#2}}

% Additional macros with subentries

\newbibmacro*{index:name:field}[6]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name:subentry}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    {\thefield{#6}}{\csfield{#6}}}

\newbibmacro*{index:name:title}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name:subentry}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{\csfield{indextitle}}}}

\newbibmacro*{index:name:subentry}[7]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}{%
    \mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\mkbibindexsubentry{#6}{#7}}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% META-FIELDS
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\DeclareLabelname{%
  \field{shortauthor}
  \field{author}
  \field{shorteditor}
  \field{editor}
  \field{translator}
}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% GENERIC BIBLIOGRAPHY MACROS
% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{author}}
    {\usebibmacro{editor}}}

\newbibmacro*{author/editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{author}}
    {\usebibmacro{editor+others}}}

\newbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\printnames{translator}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{translatorstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{authorstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{authortype}
    {}
    {\printtext[authortype]{%
       \ifbibxstring{\thefield{authortype}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{author}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{authortype}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{authortype}}}}
         {\thefield{authortype}}}}}

\newbibmacro*{editor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{editortype}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\def\abx@tempa{editors}}
       {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{editor}}
     }
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}s}}
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{editortype}}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{translator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{translator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{commentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{commentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{annotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{annotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{editor}{introduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{introduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{foreword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{foreword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{editor}{afterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{afterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext[editortype]{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}}

\endinput
```

After the proposition of Guido, there is the result : (I've just delete counter)
[image]

Comment: Welcomde to TeX.SX! A minimal example of code would be needed.

Comment: What example do you need ? The _authortitle_ style code ?

Comment: At least some hints about your changes.

Comment: As far as I understand it he does not want that every entry has its own title. He rather wants that when he uses multiple sources from that person that his name is only printed once. So he has "Doe, John: Book1 ; Doe, John: Book2 ; Doe, John: Book3" but he does want "Doe, John: Book1, Book2, Book3"

Comment: Yes @JonasDralle, it's exactly that. Any idea ?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83891/16895 to see how to group the references by author.

Comment: Thank you for the link but it doesn't work (the result is in edit in the first post)...

Comment: The solution is to redefine the `author` macro to check whether the `fullhash` of the previous author in the bibliography is the same, and if so to insert a dash. I will try to look at my code when time allows unless someone else writes up a working answer before. — By the way, from your citations, are you working on french law? Could you contact me (my username at gmail).

Comment: Thank you for your indication @ienissei but I don't want a dash but don't print the name of author if the previous author is the same. -- It's my girlfriend who works on french law, but she doesn't understand LaTeX :)

Comment: The solution would be the same, simply without adding a dash (although I do not recommend it and I have never seen it in French books — no dash usually means "no author, this is a collection" whereas a dash means "same author"). I will try to find it back for you sometime. I have a whole `biblatex` style for french law but it may still need some improvements, hence my question. There is also a class called `droit-fr` for PhDs but I am not sure whether it is still actually maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
% What's new under the sun
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
    \ifthenelse{\ifuseauthor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{author}}
        {\hspace{\bibhang}--}
        {\hspace{\bibhang}--}
}

% What you need to correct
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \mkbibbold{\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}% Make the author bold
  \newline--\space% % --- There was a spurious space in your code
% \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
}

% What you need to correct (removed bolding and spurious spaces)
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}%
    {\printnames{author}}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% % virgule au début de la ligne de titre
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
```

It should work with the standard `authortitle` style, **do *not*** modify or comment out the `bbx:savehash` bibmacro.

With random bibliographic references:

[image: Result]

---

The default style adds a dash for me and does not duplicate the author name (which is the norm for bibliographies as it helps disambiguating works from the same author from works that do not have an author).

However, I would rather recommend you stick to the default than to this solution -- the default style is the one used in France and French law.