# Biblatex, references grouped by author

Tags: biblatex, formatting

[image: example]

Hello, I have trouble formatting a biblatex bibliography. I wanted to group by authors having the works according to the years followed in separate paragraphs beneath the author's name. So far so good. But I don't know how to remove the dot in front of the first year and the blank line before each following year.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{\textsc{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}


\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\par}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space}

\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\par}{}{}



\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,article,inproceedings,incollection]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,article,inproceedings,incollection]{title}{#1}


% Commas as separators
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}



% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

% Issue/date macros removed after journal number
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\newunit
 \printfield{series}%
 \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
%  \setunit{\addspace}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% DELETED
%  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% DELETED
%  \usebibmacro{issue}% DELETED
  \newunit}

% "In:" removed for articles; issue/date macros added after note+pages macro
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
 \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
 \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{in:}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}% NEW
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue}% NEW
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
   {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}


\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \addspace\bibsentence%
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \printunit{\addcomma\space}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{first-last}


\setlength{\bibhang}{20pt}


\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{}


\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,article,inproceedings,incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,article,inproceedings,incollection]{number}{#1}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could please post a *full* compilable example?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83891/16895

Comment: If Guido's link didn't help you, you might want to specify your question a bit. What have you tried, why/how did the answer in Guido's link not work for you? Note that we will need a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just part of the bibliography code to be able to help you properly.

Comment: Any news here? Did Guido's link help you?