# Group by author in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

***Question still unanswered***

**EDIT2: Still no answer?**

How to group bibliography by author like in ieeetran. I am talking about something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with). I do not want to use ieeetran style on my entire document i just want to use this style of writing multiple bibliography entries of the same author (including horizontal line).

I would be happy to use bibliographystyle plain if possible.

Here is part of my code. I need to have second line of each entry indented and without numbers that is why renewenvironment. However i want to have a dashed line instead of author name if the authors name is repeating.

**MWEB:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibl2.bib}
@article{de2017measuring,
    title={Measuring expectations of inflation: Effects of survey mode, wording, and opportunities to revise},
    author={de Bruin, W{\"a}ndi Bruine and van der Klaauw, Wilbert and van Rooij, Maarten and Teppa, Federica and de Vos, Klaas},
    journal={Journal of Economic Psychology},
    volume={59},
    pages={45--58},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{de2017measuring2,
    title={ZZZZZ},
    author={de Bruin, W{\"a}ndi Bruine and van der Klaauw, Wilbert and van Rooij, Maarten and Teppa, Federica and de Vos, Klaas},
    journal={Journal of Economic Psychology},
    volume={59},
    pages={45--58},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

    \makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\section*{\refname}%
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
        \begin{enumerate}[label={},itemindent=*,leftmargin=4em]
            \@openbib@code
            \sloppy
            \clubpenalty4000
            \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
            \widowpenalty4000
            \sfcode`\.\@m}
        {\def\@noitemerr
            {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \end{enumerate}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    %\singlespacing
    \nocite{*}

    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibl2}

    \endgroup

    \end{document}
```

I want behavior of this type:

[image]

line instead of author name (e.g. Paul Hubert) when two (or more) article written by the same author.

as for citations i am using footnotes for reference
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added part of my code.

Comment: Thanks. Which `\documentclass` do you use? Are all needed packages in the preamble? The code should be compilable .

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "group bibliography by author". E.g., do you wish to sort the bibliography alphabetically by authors' surnames? Should repeated instances of authors be replaced by long dashes? If so, how many dashes? Please be specific.

Comment: I have added necessary details

Comment: The bib entries are still missing for a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) (MWE with bibliography)

Comment: Corrected i guess

Comment: Do you want numeric-style or authoryear-style citation call-outs? I'm guessing it's the former, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: No as i wrote i do not want numbers and i want to have indentation from second line of each entry onwards. I have added a bit clearer screenshot

Comment: @Mrowkacala What should the citations in the text look like?

Comment: @samcarter added to the main question

Comment: This very similar question has an answer that apparently works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83845/bibliography-with-per-author-numbering-and-author-year-sort/83891#83891